# Show that $p_\rho(λ) = p_{\rho_1}(λ)p_{\rho_2}(λ)$ where $p_\rho,p_{\rho_1},p_{\rho_2}$ are the characteristic polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

> Let $\rho ∈ Hom_K(V,V)$ such that $\rho = \rho_1\oplus\rho_2$ with respect to the sum $V = U_1\oplus U_2$
>   where $U_i, i = 1,2$ is invariant under $\rho$. Show that $p_\rho(λ) = p_{\rho_1}(λ)p_{\rho_2}(λ)$ where $p_\rho,p_{\rho_1},p_{\rho_2}$ are the characteristic polynomials.

My attempt:

Let $\{e_1\}^n_{i=1}$ be a basis for $U_1$ and $\{f_1\}^m_{i=1}$ be a basis for $U_2$, so the basis of V is $\{e_1,...,f_m\}$.

Now, $\rho(e_1) = a_{11}e_1+...+a_{1n}e_n, ...,\rho(e_n) = a_{n1}e_1+...+a_{nn}e_n$, $\rho(f_1) = b_{11}f_1+...+b_{1m}f_n, ...,\rho(f_m) = b_{m1}f_1+...+b_{mm}f_m$

Let

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & ... & a_{n1} \\
. &  & .\\
. &  & .\\
. &  & .\\
a_{1n} & .. & a_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$
$$
Y=\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{11} & ... & b_{m1} \\
. &  & .\\
. &  & .\\
. &  & .\\
b_{1m} & .. & a_{mm} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

So now, I want a matrix of the form $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
X & 0 \\
0 & Y \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

So that I can compute the characteristic polynomial and so that will prove the exercise. But I don't know how to get that matrix.

Comment: Im fairly certain that your block matrix is in fact the matrix of $\rho$ with respect to your basis.

Comment: How can I ensure that?

Comment: Well, the columns of the block matrix are the coordinates of $\rho(v_i)$, where $\{v_1,\dots,v_{n+m}\}$ is the basis you gave.

Comment: But how do I know that there are zeros under of $X$ and above of $Y$? I think that if $n<m$ there are zeros under $X$, but I don't know what to do with the zeros above $Y$

Comment: If you have ordered your basis so that the $e_i$’s are before the $f_i$’s, then because $\rho(f_i)$ is a linear combination of the $f_i$’s it follows that the first $n$ coordinates (those corresponding to $e_i$’s) are all 0, so the first $n$ entries in each of those columns is 0.

Comment: Ah, I get it. So it's basically this: $\rho(f_i) = 0e_1+...+0e_n+b_{i1}f_1 +... +b_{im}f_m$, right?

Comment: And also, I can forget the condition with $n$ and $m$ and use the same reasoning:
$\rho(e_i) = a_{i1}e_1+...+a_{in}e_n+0f_1 +... +0f_m$

Comment: Yes thats exactly right.